# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION runtime error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Why does the first line in the method below give me an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` runtime error?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cellIdentifier = NSStringFromClass(MessageCell)
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as MessageCell
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift does not have the introspection capabilities yet as Obj-C does.

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

}

let a = NSStringFromClass(NSString) // prints NSString
let b = NSStringFromClass(Cell) // prints _TtC11lldb_expr_04Cell
let c = NSStringFromClass(UITableViewCell) // prints UITableViewCell
```

Since the identifier gets modified you try to dequeue a non-existent cell which leads to the mentioned error.

See also [Get a user-readable version of the class name in swift (in objc NSStringFromClass was fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107658/get-a-user-readable-version-of-the-class-name-in-swift-in-objc-nsstringfromclas)

Comment: Good guess. But, I was actually using `cellIdentifier` in both places. Thanks though. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, turns out the first line is OK. It was the second line causing the crash. [UITableView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022763/uitableview-in-swift) has the solution.

Comment: yeah, the one in which you are dequeuing the cell.